# AttributeError: columns not found

Tags: python, pandas

```
>>> help(xv_train.columns)

AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-32-cb77c83d8088> in <module>()
----> 1 help(xv_train.columns)

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/scipy/sparse/base.py in __getattr__(self, attr)
    689             return self.getnnz()
    690         else:
--> 691             raise AttributeError(attr + " not found")
    692 
    693     def transpose(self, axes=None, copy=False):

AttributeError: columns not found
```

please help me to solve this error

Comment: What is `xv_train`? => `type(xv_train)`, probably a sparse matrix.

Comment: This question cannot be answered without infromation about what `xv_train` is, but clearly, whatever it is, it does not have a `columns` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Difficult to answer without more information, but this comes up with a sparse matrix. Shot in the dark, but try calling:

```
pd.DataFrame(xv_train.toarray())
```

That'll bring in a dataframe with columns. Not necessarily the column names, but then again, you never asked for that.